# Netbeans install error: The specified jdk folder does not contain jdk

Tags: java, openjdk, netbeans, jdk

During installation of Netbeans 7.3 I got this message

```
the specified jdk folder does not contain jdk
```

I have openjdk 7 installed on my system using apt-get. I tried to specify the path to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386` and also tried to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/bin` but nothing works. What should I do?

Comment: Have a look at [This](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqInstallJavahome) it might help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Got the solution.
As openjdk documentation says I installed openjdk using

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

But it's not complete installation. After that I used this command

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

It installs several extra packages. After that netbeans find jdk automatically and normal installation completed smoothly...

Comment: So you did not have the jdk installed? :/

Comment: During openjdk installation I don't know about the second command as I installed it reading an article.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the `JAVA_HOME` path.

Open `/etc/profile` with you favorite text editor, ie

```
gksudo gedit /etc/profile
```

Navigate to the end of the file and add these contents

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export JAVA_BIN
export PATH
```

Reload your system wide PATH /etc/profile with

```
. /etc/profile
```

As an option, you can run the installer with the `--javahome` option pointing to the `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386` path as such

`netbeans-installer.sh --javahome /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386`

this will force the installer to use that path for the Java version you desire.

Comment: Last command should be ./netbeans.sh --javahome /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386 ===but no, it's not working. Same result.

Comment: What are the contents of the java-7-openjdk-i386 folder?

Comment: Thanks but I got the solution.

Answer (score 0):

for me it works.
I installed Netbeans 8 and it ask me to join the jd path.

I used the first answer:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

than

`sh netbeans-8.0-linux.sh` (suppose I'm in the `/home/MYNAME/Download/` where I downloaded `.sh` file)